# How To Make Two Columns in ListView

Tags: vb.net

Textbox 1 value Add to Listbview column 1

And Textbox Two Value Add To Listview column 2

And In Side Quantity Of Numbers Are shown

Image Link

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0j4bzarlOBg/SV8ekS0B5JI/AAAAAAAAAG8/c5un3Gfl0R8/s400/SilverlightListBoxMulti.JPG

Comment: `column` (not `coloum`)

Comment: In Windows Forms at least, a `ListBox` doesn't actually contain multiple columns.  You can put whitespace in your text to make it appear so, but if you want columns then you should use a `ListView` or `DataGridView`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You want this : 
[system.windows.forms.datagridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)